# String strings with line breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, string

I am working on a portal which allow the examiner to provide a problem statement along with sample input and sample output. The issue is that when value is added to the sample input/output section it is stored as a complete string and line breaks are not getting rendered on the candidate side.
Let me show you an example to make it more clear:

[image]

[image]

You can see how the line breaks doesn't get rendered on the candidate side. What changes should i make which will allow me render text properly on client side.
Frontend: React
Backend: Nodejs

Comment: Add the JavaScript line break string escape code of `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve desired result by using white-space:  "pre-wrap".